# What does remove() method in ArrayList datatype exactly returns

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using list.remove() method in my code. I was trying to pass the returned value as a param to some function as a string so that it does both the job of returning as well as removing the object. When I print it in for loop it displays only two elements when it should print 4 . Why is it happening so ?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");
        list.add("c");
        list.add("d");

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
            Log.d("Removed+++++++++++","++++"+list.remove(i));
           // queue.remove();
        }
```

> > D/Removed+++++++++++: ++++a
> >      D/Removed+++++++++++:++++c

Why does it only print a and c when it should print a,b,c,d ?

Comment: Because the indices do change. After deleting the object at index `"0"` (`"a"`), `"b"` will stand at index `"0" `and thus `"c"` stands at index `"1"`.

Comment: Consider using a list iterator to remove items.

Comment: or loop from the back of the list `for(int i=list.size()-1;i >= 0;i--){...}`

Comment: Downvoted for lack of prior research. Heck - you already know how the method is named and on which class it lives. What exactly prevented you from reading the javadoc yourself?!

Comment: @GhostCat I read the javadoc and hence the question , after reading the javadoc I was trying to return the string as a parameter to method,but I missed the point that I need to decrement the value in loop. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It returns the element that was removed, as stated in the Javadoc:

> **E java.util.List.remove(int index)**
>
> **Returns:**
> the element previously at the specified position

It only prints "a" and "c" because it only removed "a" and "c".

When removing elements from an `ArrayList`, the indices of the following elements are decremented. You have to account for that if you wish your loop to remove all elements. Otherwise you'll skip half of the elements.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    Log.d("Removed+++++++++++","++++"+list.remove(i));
    i--;
}
```

Comment: Or maybe `remove(list.size() - 1)`, rinse and repeat until empty ;-).

Comment: Or `remove(0)` to remove the first element =)

Comment: but then you cannot print them

Comment: @Turing85 Nah, `remove(0)` involves shifting all elements left.

Comment: Thanks much :) exactly as I read in docs , I thought it will be returning me the same, but I missed the point that I need to decrement the value in for loop :)

Comment: @Turing85 *"but then you cannot print them"* why not printing the elements first (maybe in a loop) and calling `list.clear()` afterwards?

Comment: Or just do this `while(!list.isEmpty()) { Log.d(... + list.remove(0)); }`

Answer (score 3):

As Java API documentation states:

*E remove(int index) - removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.*

You may want to change your loop to while-loop if you don't want to increment the index of element you want to remove in next loop as it seems unnecessary in your example (it caused problem in your for-loop, you didn't decrement this index inside the loop again).

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
while (list.size() > 0) {
    Log.d("Removed+++++++++++","++++" + list.remove(0)); // queue.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input :). I exactly missed this point that I need to decrement the value in loop :)

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. If you find my answer helpful some way, you might want to consider upvoting it. Happy New Year :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after removing value from `ArrayList` object list inside `loop`, the size of the list decreases and your `for loop` index value is increasing by 1, so after deleting two values, your list size remains two and the i value is 2 so the condition failed and loop got terminated.

Try the code below:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");

while(list.size() > 0){
    String removingValue = list.get(0);
    if(list.remove(0) != null)
        System.out.println("After removing " + removingValue + " list size is : " + list.size());
}
```

and the output is the following:

```
After removing a list size is : 3
After removing b list size is : 2
After removing c list size is : 1
After removing d list size is : 0
```

Hope your logic cleared.

Comment: Why not `String removingValue = list.remove(0); if (removingValue != null) { ... }` since the question was about using remove to get the removed value. Your code does not use that effectively.

Comment: @Reboot you are free to give answer, and proof this output given by me is different from my source code, and what is the issue of the OP, that he is getting messages only for removing two values just because of list size getting reduced to two, many people have many options to deal with things, if you think you are also free to give your answer, Okay.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that there are two remove() methods in the ArrayList class:

```
/**
     * Removes the element at the specified position in this list.
     * Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their
     * indices).
     *
     * @param index the index of the element to be removed
     * @return the element that was removed from the list
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public E remove(int index) {
```

the other remove method looks as follows:

```
/**
     * Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
     * if it is present.  If the list does not contain the element, it is
     * unchanged.  More formally, removes the element with the lowest index
     * <tt>i</tt> such that
     * <tt>(o==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;get(i)==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;o.equals(get(i)))</tt>
     * (if such an element exists).  Returns <tt>true</tt> if this list
     * contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this list
     * changed as a result of the call).
     *
     * @param o element to be removed from this list, if present
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this list contained the specified element
     */
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
```

Comment: So even String is an object isn't it ? So how does it differentiate between boolean and string , since currently it is returning me a String ?

Comment: @Pritish, of course String is an object . The differentiation is determined based on the types of arguments you provide when you call the method. Since you provide integers (simple primitives), the method  public E remove(int index)  is being called.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :)